# Call attribute after chaining methods

Tags: python, chaining

I'm building a Python class that utilizes attribute chaining.  I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to identify when the final attribute of a chain is called and execute some processing code at that point.  After the final chained attribute is called, I'd like to process the collected data.  I realize that a processing attribute could be called explicitly at the end of the chain, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

For example:

```
o = ObjectInstance()
# Note that the attribute calling order is subjective
o('data').method_a('other data').method_c('other_data') #o.process() is called here automatically
```

**--Update--**

I've found a workaround that is specific to my situation, though it does not answer the underlying question.

For my particular case, I intend to process multiple chains separately with a single instance.   By overriding the `__call__` attribute of my class, I can check if the previous chain has been processed, and react accordingly.  I was already planning to have a separate rendering method---which can also process the previous chain--after all chains were processed, so it works for my particular scenario.

The class would look something like:

```
class Chainable:

    current_chain_data = None
    processed_chains = list()


    def __call__(self, data):
        if self.current_chain_data:
            self.process()

        #Some logic
        self.current_chain_data = data
        return self


    def method_a(self, data):
        #Some logic
        self.current_chain_data = data
        return self

    def method_b(self, data):
        #...

    def process(self, data):
        #do stuff
        self.processed_chains.append(self.current_chain_data)
        self.current_chain_data = None

    def render(self):
        if self.current_chain_data:
            self.process()

        for c in self.processed_chains:
            output += c
        return output
```

And be used like:

```
c = Chainable()

# do some chaining
c('data').method_a('other_data').method_c('other_data')

# previous chain is processed here, new chain started
c('additional_data').method_b('other_data') #...

# previous chain is processed here, output rendered
c.render()
```

Comment: "I'd like to avoid that if possible." Please don't. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, and for a simple example like the one I posted above I fully agree.  However, for my usage the key objective is to maintain (as accurately as possible) the familiar syntax of a non-Python scripting language.

Comment: I suggest that your solution is likely to confuse your users, because it is non-uniform. What happens if someone calls another method on `c` before calling `c`? Would your users expect that behaviour?

Comment: Also, you now require render to be called as the last method, or your last chain is never processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to recognise a "last" call, because a "chain" is not a language construct, but rather a consequnce of a uniform syntax combined with your own (good) practice of returning the same object from a non-functional method.

Your options are:

1. have a final process call, as you suggest (in many ways the cleanest solution);
2. perform your processing at every stage (which may or may not be a performance hit, depending on the processing, and what your methods actually do); or
3. have each method define a keyword argument that allows you to label it as the final call, in order to trigger processing.

I would suggest option 1, unless option 2 naturally produces no performance penalty, if for no other reason than it introduces the least complexity, and explicit is usually better than implicit.

Your solution of overriding `__call__` has several drawbacks: it is likely to confuse your users, because it is non-uniform; if someone calls another method on `c` before calling `c`, the behaviour might well surprise them (chain continued); and finally, you still need a final `render` call to close out the last chain, which will make such code more fragile than necessary.

Comment: I think your points are all quite valid.  I've elected to go the route of the final processing call (in this case, a render method) which will work quite well (and semantically, I might add) with the framework this project is built for.  I'm confident it will not confuse users at all, since the class mirrors almost exactly the familiar syntax of a non-Python scripting language that the class integrates directly with.   Thanks!

Comment: @CaseyKinsey Cool! If you are trying to get users to use python, you might like to provide an ordinary interface also, to wean them off what they are used to (of course, that might not apply at all in your situation).

Answer (score 0):

```
class DataObject:

        def __init__(self, data):

                self.data = data


        def method_a(self, data):

                self.data += data

                return self


        def method_c(self, data):

                self.data += data

                return self

        def process(self):

                print self.data

if __name__ == "__main__":

        o = DataObject('data')
        o.method_a('other data').method_c('other_data').process()
```

Comment: This would work if there was a definite calling order, but as I noted in my question, it is subjective.  `method_c` may very well be called before `method_a`.

Comment: @CaseyKinsey in that case you'll probably have to explicitly call .process(), I've edited to reflect that.

Comment: Yeah, I noted in my question that I may have to settle for that.  I did find a workaround for my very specific situation that I posted above, but I'm still curious if there's a Pythonic way to handle it in a more universal way that I'm unaware of.